# "The location of Firebird Client Library could not be determined."

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, firebird, client-library

I encountered a similar problem as dicussed in here:

[Firebird embedded installation issue: library could not be determined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48035341/firebird-embedded-installation-issue-library-could-not-be-determined)

I'm running a python(3.5.2) script via ubuntu (16.04.4 LTS) which is connected to a firebird database. For installing firebird I followed the instructions provided in here:

https://firebirdsql.org/manual/ubusetup.html

Now, when I run the python code the following error is displayed:

```
Soft limit starts as  :-1
Soft limit changed to :1024
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "clustering_setup.py", line 30, in <module>
    graph, posi_knoten, kanten_bewertung, auslassliste = build_netzwerk.create_graph()
  File "/home/ubuntu/Documents/Code/build_netzwerk.py", line 113, in create_graph
    datenbank_custom.start(config.idbf_file)
  File "/home/ubuntu/Documents/Code/datenbank_custom.py", line 19, in start
    con = fdb.connect(database=idbf_file, user='sysdba', password='pass')
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/fdb/fbcore.py", line 682, in connect
    load_api(fb_library_name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/fdb/fbcore.py", line 181, in load_api
    setattr(sys.modules[__name__],'api',fbclient_API(fb_library_name))
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/fdb/ibase.py", line 1398, in __init__
    raise Exception("The location of Firebird Client Library could not be determined.")
Exception: The location of Firebird Client Library could not be determined.
```

if I examine where the files are located this is what is shown to me:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ dpkg -L firebird2.5-classic-common
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/firebird2.5-classic-common
/usr/share/doc
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/qli
/usr/bin/nbackup
/usr/bin/fbstat
/usr/bin/fbtracemgr
/usr/bin/gdef
/usr/bin/gsec
/usr/bin/isql-fb
/usr/bin/gpre
/usr/bin/gbak
/usr/bin/fbsvcmgr
/usr/bin/gfix
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/firebird
/usr/lib/firebird/2.5
/usr/lib/firebird/2.5/UDF
/usr/lib/firebird/2.5/UDF/ib_udf.so
/usr/lib/firebird/2.5/UDF/fbudf.so
/usr/sbin
/usr/sbin/fb_lock_print
/usr/share/doc/firebird2.5-classic-common
```

output of `locate libfbclient`:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfbclient.so.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfbclient.so.2.5.4
/usr/share/doc/libfbclient2
/var/cache/apt/archives/libfbclient2_2.5.4.26856.ds4-1build1_amd64.deb
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfbclient2:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfbclient2:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfbclient2:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfbclient2:amd64.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfbclient2:amd64.preinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfbclient2:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libfbclient2:amd64.symbols
```

applying `cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*` leads to:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Documents/Code$ cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfakeroot
# Multiarch support
/lib/i386-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
/lib/i686-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/i686-linux-gnu
# libc default configuration
/usr/local/lib
# Multiarch support
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa-egl
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa
```

result for `ldconfig -p | grep libfbclient`

```
libfbclient.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfbclien.so.2
```

thats the script im running!

```
from datetime import datetime
import funcs
import build_netzwerk
from scipy.optimize import minimize_scalar
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import funcs_nachbearb
import config

start = datetime.now()

# abstandsgewichteten Graphen berechnen
graph, posi_knoten, kanten_bewertung, auslassliste = build_netzwerk.create_graph()

# zurückgegebene Werte bestimmen
if config.clusteringtyp == 'sohlhoehe':
    kanten_durchfluss = kanten_bewertung[1].copy()
    kanten_bewertung = kanten_bewertung[0].copy()
elif config.clusteringtyp == 'durchfluss':
    kanten_durchfluss = kanten_bewertung.copy()
else:
    kanten_durchfluss = kanten_bewertung.copy()
    kanten_bewertung = None

# minimalen Optimierungsfaktor bestimmen
print(datetime.now() - start)
erg_min = minimize_scalar(funcs.optimiere_cluster, args=(graph, kanten_bewertung, auslassliste, 'min'),
                          bounds=(0, 10), method='bounded')
# print(erg_min)

# maximalen Optimierungsfaktor bestimmen
print(datetime.now() - start)
erg_max = minimize_scalar(funcs.optimiere_cluster, args=(graph, kanten_bewertung, auslassliste, 'max'),
                          bounds=(erg_min.x, 10), method='bounded')
# print(erg_max)

# besten Optimierungsfaktor bestimmen
print(datetime.now() - start)
clustersammlung = funcs.bruteforce_optim(erg_min.x, erg_max.x, graph, kanten_bewertung, auslassliste,
                                         kanten_durchfluss)

print(datetime.now() - start)

# Clusternummerierung soll von 0 bis Anzahl gewünschter Cluster laufen
funcs_nachbearb.transform_clusternummern(clustersammlung)

# Bewertung der Cluster berechnen
print(funcs_nachbearb.cluster_bewertung(clustersammlung, graph, kanten_durchfluss))

# Clusterhierarchie berechnen
print(funcs_nachbearb.cluster_hierarchie(clustersammlung, graph))

# Schächte der Messstationen ausgeben
ms = ""
for key in clustersammlung.keys():
    ms = ms + clustersammlung[key].endpoint + ", "
ms.rstrip(", ")
print("Messstationen: " + ms)

# Einflussgebiete auf die Messstationen ausgeben
print("Einflussgebiete:")
for key in clustersammlung.keys():
    print("Einflussgebiet von Cluster " + str(key) + ": " + ", ".join(clustersammlung[key].nodes))


print(datetime.now() - start)

# entstehenden Grpahen mit Clustern zeichnen
funcs.draw_clustered_graph(graph, posi_knoten, clustersammlung)
plot.show()


print(datetime.now() - start)
```

datenbank_custom:

```
import fdb

con = None


def start(idbf_file):
    """
    Verbindung mit idbf-Datenbank aufbauen

    :param idbf_file: (str) Dateipfad zur Datenbank
    """

    global con
    con = fdb.connect(database=idbf_file, user='sysdba', password='pass')


def stop():
    """
    Verbindung mit idbf-Datenbank trennen
    """

    global con
    con.close()


def read_from_db_single(sqlstatement):
    """
    Allgemeine Funktion um einen einzelnen Wert aus dem IDBF-File auszulesen

    :param sqlstatement: (str) SQL-Abfrage zum auslesen eines Wertes

    :return results: abgefragter Wert
    """

    curs = con.cursor()  # Use a client side cursor so you can access curs.rowcount
    curs.execute(sqlstatement)
    results = curs.fetchone()

    if results:
        results = results[0]

    del curs
    return results


def read_from_db(sqlstatement):
    """
    Allgemeine Funktion um Daten aus dem IDBF-File auszulesen

    :param sqlstatement: (str) SQL-Abfrage an Datenbank

    :return results: Rückgabe der Abfrage
    """

    curs = con.cursor()  # Use a client side cursor so you can access curs.rowcount
    curs.execute(sqlstatement)
    results = curs.fetchall()

    del curs
    return results


def read_network(infotyp=None):
    """
    Gibt die Knoten und die Kanten für das Kanalnetzmodel zurück.
    Alle Schachttypen sind Knoten, alle Haltungen, Sonderbauwerke, ... sind Kanten

    :param infotyp: (str) String zur Erweiterung der SELECT-Werte an die Kanten

    :return results_knoten: (list(tuple(str, float, float))) Listen der Knoteninformationen
    :return results_kanten: (list(tuple(str, float, float, [...]))) Listen der Kanteninformationen;
                            list(tuple(name, schachtoben, -unten, infotyp[i])
    :return results_sonderkanten: (list(tuple(str, float, float))) Listen der Sonderkanteninformationen
    """

    erweiterung = ''
    if infotyp is not None:
        erweiterung = infotyp

    knoten = "SELECT name,XKOORDINATE,YKOORDINATE from SCHACHT UNION " + \
             "SELECT name,XKOORDINATE,YKOORDINATE from SPEICHERSCHACHT UNION " + \
             "SELECT name,XKOORDINATE,YKOORDINATE from AUSLASS;"

    kanten = "SELECT name,schachtoben,schachtunten" + erweiterung + " from ROHR UNION " + \
             "SELECT name,schachtoben,schachtunten" + erweiterung + " from HREGLER UNION " + \
             "SELECT name,schachtoben,schachtunten" + erweiterung + " from QREGLER;"

    sonderkanten = "SELECT name,schachtoben,schachtunten from DROSSEL UNION " + \
                   "SELECT name,schachtoben,schachtunten from GRUNDSEITENAUSLASS UNION " + \
                   "SELECT name,schachtoben,schachtunten from PUMPE UNION " + \
                   "SELECT name,schachtoben,schachtunten from SCHIEBER UNION " + \
                   "SELECT name,schachtoben,schachtunten from WEHR;"

    curs = con.cursor()  # Use a client side cursor so you can access curs.rowcount

    curs.execute(knoten)
    results_knoten = list(curs.fetchall())

    curs.execute(kanten)
    results_kanten = list(curs.fetchall())

    curs.execute(sonderkanten)
    results_sonderkanten = list(curs.fetchall())

    del curs

    return results_knoten, results_kanten, results_sonderkanten
```

I'd appreciate your advise on that, because I have absolutely no clue how to fix that particular issue!

Comment: What is the output of `locate libfbclient` (you may need to do an `sudo updatedb` first if you installed Firebird recently)?

Comment: Did you install package `libfbclient2`?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, I install _libfbclient2_ already, but still the error is displayed.

Comment: Could you edit the question and add it there? That makes it more readable than in the comments. I'll see if I can reproduce this and provide a solution.

Comment: @Mark sure, i'll do that !

Comment: I'm afraid I can't reproduce it (Ubuntu 17.10, libfbclient2 3.0.2, python 3.6 and fdb 1.8). I'll try to find the time to install a clean 16.04 VM and see if I can reproduce it that way

Comment: What is the output of `python3 -c 'import struct;print( 8 * struct.calcsize("P"))'`? (if you are using another python executable for running your application, then substitute that).

Comment: @Mark, my output is 64 for that case

Comment: Ok, then the only other idea I had to explain your problem is also out (32 bit python can't use a 64 bit libfbclient).

Comment: In any case, did you try `sudo ldconfig` as I suggested in my answer?

Comment: i tried that, but the error is still present

Comment: What is the output for `ldconfig -p | grep libfbclient`?

Comment: @Mark, I added the output for your requested to the question. what do you conclude from that?

Comment: I assume the libfbclien.so.2 in there is a typo, otherwise it would seem the symlink is wrong? Could you explicitly add the `fdb.connect` string of your application to the question, the only other thing I can think of is that you explicitly specify the property `fb_library_name`. Or try explicitly setting `fb_library_name='/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfbclient.so.2'` in the connect method.

Comment: Hey @Mark, im afraid I don't exactly get what you are asking for. I should just apply "fb_library_name='/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfbclient.so.2" ?

Comment: Could you show the source of your application that connects to Firebird?

Comment: hi @Mark, sorry for my late reply. i added the running script to the current description  up there. would u also need to see all the importet scripts additionally? thanks a lot for your support until here!!

Comment: The code in `datenbank_custom.py` is probably the most relevant.

Comment: have attached that one as well

Answer (score 4):

I installed Ubuntu 16.04.4 as a fresh VM, and only did an `sudo apt-get update`/`sudo apt-get upgrade`

And then did the following:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
sudo apt install libfbclient2
mkdir fdb-experiment
cd fdb-experiment
pip3 install fdb
nano connect.py
```

With `connect.py`:

```
import fdb

# 172.26.69.161 is my Windows machine with Firebird
con = fdb.connect(dsn='172.26.69.161:d:/data/db/testdatabase.fdb', user='sysdba', password='masterkey')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("select * from rdb$database")
print(cur.fetchall())
```

Then:

```
python3 connect.py
```

Output:

```
[(None, 225, None, 'ISO8859_1                      ')]
```

I did have to restart my VM in between because of some networking problems to the Windows host OS (which is running the Firebird server I used). I can only reproduce your problem if I perform `sudo apt remove libfbclient2`.

In other words, I can't reproduce your problem. The only thing I can think of is that maybe you're using an older version of fdb (I'm using 1.8) which locates the client library in a different way (but as your stacktrace has the same line numbers I see if I remove `libfbclient2`, that is likely not the case).

You might want to try if running `sudo ldconfig` fixes the problem, this will rebuild the cache of shared libraries. If that doesn't work, then check if `cat /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*` lists `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` (if it doesn't, then I'm not entirely sure what would be the correct course of action to fix that).

Answer (score 0):

Windows users:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
import os

# I'm using the 'portable' version of firebird 2.5 32bits and Python 3.11 32bits
# setting the firebird client path
os.environ['PATH'] = r'D:\Portable\database\firebird\Firebird25\bin;%PATH%'

# if you're running on the cmd line terminal set the path: 
# set PATH=D:\Portable\database\firebird\Firebird25\bin;%PATH%

#database string connection
db_uri = 'firebird+fdb://sysdba:masterkey@localhost:3050/C:/mydata/data.fdb'

engine = create_engine(db_uri, echo=True)

# Create a connection
conn = engine.connect()

# Execute a SQL query
result = conn.execute(text('SELECT FIRST 1 * FROM MyTable'))

# Iterate through the results
for row in result:
    print(row)

# Close the connection
conn.close()
```

Source: [Github](https://gist.github.com/rubgithub/0cc0663dc067568af25e254bc0d93a47)