# How to solve that my Python exe is not running on other computer because of Firebird Client Library

Tags: python, exe, firebird, pyinstaller

I have created a Python exe with **PyInstaller**.

My exe is well running on the 'source' computer.

When I tried to run it on an other computer I get this issue :

```
C:\Users\maell\Desktop\CreateSQL app V1\app>app.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 68, in <module>
  File "app.py", line 44, in show_DataBase_results
  File "usefull_fonctions_fdb.py", line 5, in open_database
  File "site-packages\fdb\fbcore.py", line 784, in connect
  File "site-packages\fdb\fbcore.py", line 220, in load_api
  File "site-packages\fdb\ibase.py", line 1385, in __init__
Exception: The location of Firebird Client Library could not be determined.
[9340] Failed to execute script app
```

The issue is clearly about the **Firebird Client Library**.
I try to understand why I have this issue and how to solve it.

- I first though that maybe it is beacause the fdb library is import in a 'sub-file' so it is an hidden import and PyInstaller don't see it. I imported fdb in the main app file, but the issue still the same.
- I also have looked into my environment variable, thinking that maybe my other computer miss one about fdb, but I didn't see any fdb related environment variable in my 'source' computer.

Do you have any ideas why I have this issue ? Is it a file I need to put in the exe directory ? Or something I have to tell PyInstaller ?

**EDIT :**
By adding fbclient.dll in the directory of my exe, the error has changed :

```
(base) C:\Users\maell\Desktop\app>app.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 67, in <module>
  File "app.py", line 43, in show_DataBase_results
  File "usefull_fonctions_fdb.py", line 5, in open_database
  File "site-packages\fdb\fbcore.py", line 848, in connect
fdb.fbcore.DatabaseError: ('Error while connecting to database:\n- SQLCODE: -904\n- unavailable database', -904, 335544375)
[11120] Failed to execute script app
```

I checked, the database is in the good directory (it is working on the 'source' computer).

Comment: Do you actually have the Firebird client library installed on your system (and of a bitness matching your python)? If you don't want to depend on the Firebird client library, consider switching to pyfirebirdsql, as that implements the Firebird wire protocol in pure Python.

Comment: Firebird Client Library is not install on my 'new' computer system. I would like my exe to work without needing this installation. I will take a look to PyFireBaseSQL !

Comment: You may try to use Firebird 2.5 Embedded and copy it into your application folder - as it was described in one of the articles I linked. You can not use SAL databases without SQL server. But you sometimes may choose between a stand-alone server and a server embedded into your application.

Answer (score 1):

All in all, Firebird Client Library is part of Firebird Server not Python (though I do not know what specifically is called FCL by Python, but hope it is not deviating from standard terms), and should be called "fbclient.dll", alternatively may go as "fbembed.dll" or "gds32.dll". Thing is, though, that that DLL is dynamically loaded when you try to actually connect to the database server.

> File "app.py", line 44, in show_DataBase_results
>    File "usefull_fonctions_fdb.py", line 5, in open_database

Your log shows that your `app.exe` actually tried to connect to Firebird Server to read some "results" from some "Database". To do it - Firebird Server is required. It is missed - and reading of the database fails.

Now, why your installation - not the installed application but mere installation - needs to read databases, that looks strange for me, but I don't know.
Find it and fix it so installer itself does not try to ask Firebird Server to read from Firebird databases, then the error would be gone.

P.S. also see those discussions:

- ["The location of Firebird Client Library could not be determined."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49360384)
- [Connecting to Firebird database from Windows local network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48644672)
- [Firebird embedded installation issue: library could not be determined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48035341)

P.P.S. also, a lifehack:

> Do you have any ideas? Is it a file? Or something?

When you ask yourself questions like that - try using `SysInternals Process Monitor` to check which specific file (if it was a file) and in which specific folders your "app.exe" looks for before throwing that error. Or maybe it looks for registry data not for file, etc - registry logs are also accumulated by the ProcMon.

Comment: It doesn't use the term FCL, it uses the term "Firebird Client Library", which is a proper and correct term to refer to the library irrespective of its file name and platform. You can see the error raised [here in the FDB sources](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/fdb/blob/master/fdb/ibase.py#L1385).

Comment: FCL is just an abbreviation of previously used and spelled in full "Firebird Client Library". P.S. I looked into the sources and see there a "magic constant" `'fbclient.dll'` copy-pasted here and there without any alternative file names... Sigh... Even Delphi libs were done better in this aspect.

Comment: For the question "why your installation needs to read databases ?" : my code create a SQL query and I want to test it by query the database. That's why I need to read database.

Comment: I tried to add the file fbclient.dll to my exe directory. The error has now changed. I edited my first post with the new erro.

Comment: @LCMa because "database" here is not file with data, it is "database management system", a service of Firebird Server running and ready to run commands form your application. You have to install it, then to create required user and password, unless you use SYSDBA/masterkey pair (which is not reliable)

Comment: `my code create a SQL query and I want to test it by query the database` - why should installer do it? installer might unpack a ready-made database and then leave it to the application to run and test queries. Anyway, your application to work would need the SQL server available and ready to serve its requests, too. Firebird Server may be present on some remote computer. Or, if locally, it may be running as a stand-alone program. Or be *embedded* into your program like SQLite. But, I do not think it would be easy to make a no-install embedded server out of FB 3.x. FB 2.5 is simpler there.

Comment: @LCMa For the second error, you should really post a new question. Don't make your questions a moving target.

Answer (score 1):

Although FDB is a Python driver to connect to Firebird, it also requires the native Firebird client library (`fbclient.dll` on Windows, `libfbclient.so` on Linux). I don't know PyInstaller, but I assume it only packages Python code or requires native dependencies in a specific location.

The error indicates that you do not have the Firebird client library installed on your system, or if it is installed, it doesn't have the same bitness as your Python executable. If Python is 32 bit, you need the 32 bit Firebird client library, if 64 bit, then 64 bit.

You will need to install the Firebird client library (eg using the Firebird installer and use the minimal client install), or find out how you can explicitly include the dependency using PyInstaller. Alternatively, you could use the pure-Python Firebird driver [pyfirebirdsql](https://pypi.org/project/firebirdsql/) which doesn't need a native dependency.

Comment: he would most probably need not only client but the server itself too, and of proper version. The root questions is what and why installer tries to read from databases. Unless we know it - all other solutions are guesswork.

Comment: Q.E.D. He needs a server running locally, not merely connection to remote server

Comment: @Arioch'The He only needs the client for this, of course he'll need a server somewhere to connect to, but this error by itself just means that the client is not installed.

Comment: Guess my helpdesk experience kicks in sometimes :-) When a local installer messes with databases it is most probably local databases, and then it is most probably a mistake, or if intended then needs local server.